# Vue + Axios: Making a GET request to a third-party website throws CORS error

Tags: vue.js, axios

I'm trying to make a get request to a third-party website from my vue app. It's a public website, such as stackoverflow.com for example.

```js
mounted() {
    axios.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
},
```

I'm getting this:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stackoverflow.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Same thing happens if I upload my project on a web server. It works fine if I make the request from an Express.js app.

Is there a workaround for this? I really don't understand why it would work from a server and not from a browser. I also tried uploading the project on a web server, still the same.

Comment: **CORS** mean **Cross-Origin Resource Sharing**... Not all server will let you fetch from they API or website. As Alex write Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'. Is not only the frontEnd (client) but also  the backEnd (server) need it.

Comment: Okay but I'm not trying to access some private API, it's a public website?

Comment: You need to proxy your requests to whatever API that's missing CORS header in their response.

Comment: I Use the application **Postman** to debug without the CORS. The url you are display maybe is not ok if I refer to this doc **https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication** Do you have access to the server side?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like its because you are requesting a HTTPS resource from localhost which is HTTP by default. Try requesting HTTP only?

Alternatively, add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'` header to your request.

Also, I recommend also using the `vue-axios` library to configure your `axios`.

For example

```
import axios from "axios";
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
```

Comment: Neither of those helped, thanks for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

First complete your header request then convert your lifecycle to `created`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).